# write python package to run inside and outside django

Tags: python, django

I'm writing python helper package to run inside my django project, but I want to use it also inside other regular python code (e.g. outside of django).

The issue is that I want to take the settings from django conf.settings or from some other module if it is outside django. E.g. something like:

```
try:
     from django.conf import settings
except ImportError:
     import my_settings as settings

value = settings.SOME_SETTINGS
```

The problem is that the django.conf import does not fail, since django is installed. So the question is what is the standard way to check if I'm inside django or not?

thanks.

Comment: I don't know about being inside django or not, but IMHO it's best practice anyway to use virtualenvs to isolate different projects from each other. Thus you don't install django gobally, meaning you can create a venv for your helper package which then doesn't find django. Alternatives could be to not use imports, but instead parametrize your code with a settings-object, e.g. through an init-method of some sort. Pass this the django-settings, or your settings.

Comment: I agree. But since I want my code to be used by others - this does not help....

Answer (score 3):

You can append the path to your Django app and then import the app's settings and use it like in a Django app:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/django/app')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from django.conf import settings
```

you can also drop the `sys.path.append` as long as you get the settings right !

Inside Django you can check if the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is in the `os.environ` or not then load it:

```
# If we are outside a Django app append the app path
#  to the python path to import the setting
if 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' not in os.environ:
    sys.path.append('/path/to/your/django/app')
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

# This way the setting will be imported in both cases
from django.conf import settings
```

Comment: I want to check if I'm inside django, so my code could be configured from django settings if it is inside django or from dedicated settings moudle if it is not